# Изменение состояния ГПСЧ в gmp

Tags: c

Нужно получить большое случайное простое число. Для работы с длинной арифметикой использую библиотеку **gmp**. Код получается примерно таким

```
mpz_t p;
mpz_t p_max;
mpz_t two_mpz;
mpz_init(p);
mpz_init(p_max);
mpz_init_set_d(two_mpz, 2);
mpz_pow_ui(p_max, two_mpz, 256);
gmp_randstate_t randstate;
gmp_randinit_default(randstate);
mpz_urandomm(p, randstate, p_max);
mpz_nextprime(p, p);
```

Проблема в том, что значение **p** всегда одно и то же. Видимо это связано с тем, что состояние ГПСЧ каждыйраз одно и то же. А как его изменить?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: gmp_randseed попробуйте

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, спасибо, работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция gmp_randseed(), выношу из комментария.

Answer (score 1):

Суть в том, чтоб состояние ГПСЧ (seed) зависело от некого пусть не случайного, но меняющегося значения, например от времени. Для этого нужно использовать функцию `gmp_randseed`. Таким образом мой код расширяется до:

```
mpz_t p;
mpz_t p_max;
mpz_t two_mpz;
mpz_init(p);
mpz_init(p_max);
mpz_init_set_d(two_mpz, 2);
mpz_pow_ui(p_max, two_mpz, 256);
gmp_randstate_t randstate;
gmp_randinit_default(randstate);

time_t t1 = time(NULL);
gmp_randseed_ui(randstate, t1);

mpz_urandomm(p, randstate, p_max);
mpz_nextprime(p, p);
```